# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Reservation_Contacts' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a many to many relation between reservations and contacts and when I try to add a new contact to a reservation following error occurs.

```
    _db.Reservations.Add(reservation);
    reservation.Contacts.Add(user.Contact);
    _db.SaveChanges();
```

I think there is some problems with my table definition so i copy paste create script of my table.
I make both of reservaionId and contactId primary key in reservation_contact Table. is it wrong?
My Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reservation_Contacts](
    [Reservation_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Contact_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Reservation_Contacts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Reservation_Id] ASC,
    [Contact_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reservation_Contacts]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Reservation_Contacts_Contact] FOREIGN KEY([Contact_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Contact] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reservation_Contacts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Reservation_Contacts_Contact]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reservation_Contacts]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Reservation_Contacts_Reservation] FOREIGN KEY([Reservation_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reservation] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reservation_Contacts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Reservation_Contacts_Reservation]
GO
```

Comment: can you shouw the Insert statement that you are using..? that error is pretty much explains itself.. what you are doing is trying to send in a value in an Identity field or a field that has some constraints on it which means you `CANNOT add or Insert Duplicates` The Error from quickly glancing is happening in the `Reservation Tables Id` Field

Comment: please post the example insert query hat fails.

Comment: Do you also have access to a `DBA` where you are I would instill the help from your DBA or Lead Developer` sounds like you have been spinning your wheels on this for a few..

Comment: You're filling the e.g. `ContactID` while it's an 'identity' - or some other table. You need to put full model etc.

Comment: @Dhawalk INSERT INTO [Hotel].[dbo].[Reservation_Contacts]
           ([Reservation_Id],[Contact_Id])
     VALUES
           (9,11)

Comment: can you fire select * from [Hotel].[dbo].[Reservation_Contacts] where [Contact_Id] = 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't send in contact_id in your insert, it is an identity, it will be autogenerated.

Comment: I want to add a contact to my reservation. it shouldn't generate automatically.

Comment: Then contactid shoudl not be an identity field inthe table structure.